# Styling specific rows of a table using pseudo-classes

Tags: html, css

Say I have a header and a list of 10 rows. How would I change the text color of rows 1-3 using a pseudo class?

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #a9cdeb;
}

tr td:last-child{ 
    font-style: italic; 
}

tbody tr:   {
    color: #FF0004;
}
```

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz1smy14/)**

Comment: Unfortunately you have to do it one by one `tr:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(2), tr:nth-child(3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this.

```
tr:nth-child(3), tr:nth-child(4), tr:nth-child(5){
   color: red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cz1smy14/5/)

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is right, You can try this

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td{ /* select odd rows cell */
   color: #fff; /* applied white color */
}
```

OR you can try this

```
tr:nth-child(-n+5) td{ /* this will include <th> rows so i have used -5 */
   color: blue;
}
```

### [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz1smy14/7/)

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz1smy14/1/)

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to change the font from rows 1, 2, and 3, then leave the remaining rows unchanged

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
tr:nth-child(3),tr:nth-child(4),tr:nth-child(5){
   color:red;
   font-family: cursive; 
}
```

It change both font and color.

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cz1smy14/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tr:nth-child(-n+5) td {
   background-color: #a9cdeb;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5n0yucf/)